# Arbitrary waveform generator (How does the input of AWG affects the output)

Tags: sampling

How should one choose the sampled input for AWG so that it gives a waveform similar to the ideal waveform?
I have a data set for voltage signal sampled over time of 1 ns, which I am entering as an input for the AWG function which resamples the data at 0.05 ns and gives a waveform. There is a distortion in the AWG waveform with respect to the ideal one. For AWG, Vout(t) =∑ Vi h( -  ∆), where h is the impulse response function of the instrument. 
It is given in the question that it is possible to correct for the distortion by transforming input Vi in a special way.

Comment: I don't think this is a question for SO. Try this: http://physics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanx for point that out, will try at SE.